# Change speed of a rectangle in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

It's my first question here. I just learn canvas in JavaScript and I found a problem while adding the speed. I want to stop the rectangle if its x exceeds the width of the canvas. I am just a beginner, so please help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #canvas{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400">Your browser doesn't support canvas</canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var cnxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
        x = 0;
        y = 50;
        var t;
        function draw(){
            cnxt.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
            cnxt.beginPath();
            cnxt.rect(x,y,25,25);
            cnxt.fillStyle = 'red';
            cnxt.fill();
            var timePassed = (performance.now()-t)/1000;
            var fps = Math.round(1/ timePassed);
            
            let speed = 100;
            
            cnxt.font = '25px Arial';
            cnxt.fillStyle = 'black';
            cnxt.fillText("FPS: " + fps, 20,30);
            t = performance.now();
            
            x += (speed * timePassed);
            if (x >= 400 - 25){
                speed = 0;
            }
            window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
            
        }
        draw();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Speed is distance divided by time.  Increase the distance and/or decrease the time and you've increased the speed. Decrease the distance and/or increase the time and you've decreased the speed. Decrease the distance to zero and it's stopped. You have a variable named `speed` however, that you define as 100 every time you call the `draw` function. So it will never be anything but 100. If you defined outside of the `draw` function however, you'd be able to change it much easier.

Comment: I understand a little bit but I still can't fix it..

Comment: The rectangle doesn't move at all in my browser. Is this correct?

Comment: @cachius yes, when I add the speed it disappears! I didn't understand how speed works.